# On the expected value of an infinite product of gaussian random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

I need your expertise in solving the following problem:

Let $Y_{1},Y_{2},...$ be a sequence of gaussian independent random variables
with zero mean and unit variance. Let $X_{i}=\exp \left( a_{i}Y_{i}\right) $
, where we suppose that $\sum \limits_{i\geq 1}a_{i}Y_{i}\rightarrow Y$ a.s.

Is that $E\left[ \prod \limits_{i=1}^{\infty }X_{i}\right] <\infty $?

Comment: It depends on the behaviour of $\{a_i\}_{i\geq 1}$. Jensen's inequality only gives a lower bound for such expected value, $\exp\sum_{i\geq 1}a_i$.  What do we know about such sequence?

Comment: We can added, for example, the hypothesis that $\left \vert a_{i}\right \vert
<1$ for all i

Comment: Still not enough to ensure that $\sum_{i\geq 1}a_i$ is finite. If $\sum_{i\geq 1}a_i=+\infty$ the wanted expected value is $+\infty$ by Jensen's inequality, as already mentioned.

Comment: Actually the wanted expected value is finite iff $\{a_i\}_{i\geq 1}\in \ell^1\cap \ell^2$, by the properties of the log-normal distribution.

Comment: how to show that under the assumption that the cofficients $a_{i}$ are absolutely summable the expected value is finite?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : How are you using Jensen's inequality?  I would think Fatou's lemma is more appropriate here.  From that and an MGF result for Gaussians, we conclude that if $\sum a_i^2 < \infty$ then the desired expectation is finite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assumption $\displaystyle\sum_{i\geq 1}a_{i}Y_{i}\rightarrow Y$ a.s. is crucial, here, because (together with $EY_i=0$) it's equivalent with $\displaystyle\sum_{i\geq 1}a^2_{i}<\infty$ (cf. [a.s. convergence of sum of normal random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633290/a-s-convergence-of-sum-of-normal-random-variables)). Since $\displaystyle Ee^{a_iY_i}=e^{a^2_{i}/2}$, we have (using the independence of the $X_i$ in the first step)
$$E\left[ \prod_{i=1}^{\infty }X_{i}\right]\le\prod_{i=1}^{\infty }EX_{i}=\exp{\left(\frac12\sum_{i\geq 1}a^2_{i}\right)} <\infty.$$
Because of $EY_i=0$, assumptions about $\displaystyle\sum_{i\geq 1}a_{i}$ are not necessary.
EDIT: The strict reasoning would be
$$E\left[ \prod_{i=1}^nX_{i}\right]=\prod_{i=1}^nEX_{i}\le\exp{\left(\frac12\sum_{i\geq 1}a^2_{i}\right)} <\infty,$$ so $$E\left[ \prod_{i=1}^{\infty }X_{i}\right]\le\liminf_{n\to\infty} \prod_{i=1}^nEX_{i}\le\exp{\left(\frac12\sum_{i\geq 1}a^2_{i}\right)} <\infty$$ due to Fatou's lemma, but that's fairly obvious.
REMARK: It's actually possible to prove $$E\left[ \prod_{i=1}^{\infty }X_{i}\right]=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty }EX_{i},$$ but the proof isn't exactly obvious. Let $$Z_n=\prod_{i=1}^nX_{i}=\exp{\left(\sum^n_{i= 1}a_{i}Y_i\right)}.$$ Denoting by $\mathcal{F}_n$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, we see that $$E(Z_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n)=Z_n\,EX_{n+1}=Z_n\,e^{a^2_{n+1}/2}\ge Z_n,$$ i.e. $Z_n$ is a non-negative submartingale. Moreover, it's quadratically integrable, since $$EZ^2_n=\exp{\left(2\sum^n_{i=1}a^2_{i}\right)}\le\exp{\left(2\sum_{i\geq 1}a^2_{i}\right)}$$
If we set $\displaystyle S_n=\sup_{k\le n}Z_k$ and $S_\infty=\sup Z_k$, we have due to [Doob's martingale inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_inequality) $$ES_n\le(ES^2_n)^{1/2}\le 2(EZ^2_n)^{1/2}\le2\exp{\left(\sum_{i\geq 1}a^2_{i}\right)}<\infty$$ and (using Fatou's lemma) $ES\infty\le2\exp{\left(\sum_{i\geq 1}a^2_{i}\right)}<\infty$, so we can use the dominated convergence theorem, and thus $$E\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}Z_n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}EZ_n.$$

Comment: How did you push the expectation inside the product?  Are you using some kind of dominated convergence theorem?  You can use Fatou to get an inequality.  Actually, inequality seems all that is needed here.

Comment: How does independence imply the first step? Independence certainly implies $E[\prod_{i=1}^k X_i] =\prod_{i=1}^k E[X_i]$ for any $k$.

Comment: Consider $\{Z_i\}$ independent with $P[Z_i=0]=1-1/i$, $P[Z_i=i]=1/i$ for $i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.  Then $E[Z_i]=1$ for all $i$ but $E[\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} Z_i]=0\neq \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}E[Z_i]$.

Comment: @Michael I've added a remark showing that we can exchange expectation and limit in this case, indeed. You were correct to suspect that wouldn't be trivial, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the note.  The above looks good, except I did not follow how Doob implies $E[S_n^2] \leq 4E[Z_n^2]$ (I'm trying to use $P[S_n>x] \leq E[Z_n]/x$ for all $x$ but I'm not seeing it).  I'll give +1 anyway.  An alternative route might be to use the "bounded moment convergence theorem" (a special case of "uniform integrability") to note there is a $C<\infty$ such that $E[Z_n^2]\leq C$ for all $n$.

Comment: @Michael Well, for the the inequality I used, you'll have to follow my link a bit down that page, until the paragraph "Further inequalities". In their notation, that would be $$\|S_n\|_p\le\frac{p}{p-1}\|Z_n\|_p$$ for $p>1$. I used it for $p=2$, because that was simpler, the inequality fails for $p=1$, or rather, it's more complicated. Candidly, I don't recall the proof, though I knew it, when I worked in that area. That was back in the end of the 70s, so have mercy, please! ;)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that lower part of the page.